# How to show raw XML string in Telerik:RadGrid columns without rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, radgrid, dataformat

I have a `telerik:GridBoundColumn` in my `telerik:RadGrid` as a string type with some XML codes.

How can I show that column (raw XML) in that `RadGrid` without rendering?

My problems:
my grid direction is right to left for some reason...
so at first I should change the xml direction like below :

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Settings" FilterControlAltText="Filter Settings column" DataFormatString="<span style='direction:ltr;'>{0}</span>"
    HeaderText="Settings" SortExpression="Settings" 
    UniqueName="Settings" FilterImageToolTip="Filter" HtmlEncode="false">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

Currently we have an XML string with `ltr` direction in grid. After that I change to `HtmlEncode="TRUE"`, but by doing so I lose the `ltr` direction.
so I set `HtmlEncode` back to `false`.

I figured out I can use `<xmp>` or `<pre>` elements. But with `<xmp>` I have some replacement of `<` and `>` in grid and also it has been deprecated... and with `<pre>` I should change all `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` in my database, which is unfeasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add handler for onItemDataBound for your Grid

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
            AllowSorting="True" PageSize="50" ShowFooter="True" AllowPaging="True" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" ShowStatusBar="true" 
                onitemdatabound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">
```

And codebehind:

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
 {
            if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
            {
                GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
                item["XmlColumn1"].Text = Server.HtmlEncode(item["XmlColumn1"].Text);
                item["XmlColumn2"].Text = Server.HtmlEncode(item["XmlColumn2"].Text);
            }

  }
```

Should do the trick.